# Why doesn't the AppComponent have an ngOnInit function by default?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

On generating an Angular project using the CLI, the root component - AppComponent does not have an ngOnInit block but every other component generated has an ngOnInit block. Is it wrong to have an ngOnInit in the root component?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong to have an ngOnInit in the root component. ***But there is no need.***

By the definition, root component is just called once like `<app-root></app-root>` in the index.html. And **not called by any other components**. thus, root component would not have `@Input()` bindings that `ngOnInit` assured set properly.

not-viable.component.html:

```
<app-root [someInput]="variable"></app-root>
```

**Conclusion**

You can have `ngOnInit` in the root component, but `constructor` can do the same thing without any flaw.